# Using python requests with an API key that requires spaces

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, api, rest

I need to POST data to an API endpoint using the python requests library with application/json content-type but am getting errors due to the API key having a space in it.

API Key format:

```
Authorization: Token d6bf96a81a58bf6e99ad1f819b244242797c0c07
```

Successful curl request:

```
curl -k -H "Authorization: Token d6bf96a81a58bf6e99ad1f819b244242797c0c07" "https://myurlhere.com/api/status/" --data "status=Good&value=foobar"
```

Failed Python:

```
import requests
url="https://myurlhere.com/api/status/"
headers={"Authorization": "Token d6bf96a81a58bf6e99ad1f819b244242797c0c07","content-type":"application/json}
data="status=Good&value=foobar"

requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
```

The python request returns a 403, additional debugging shows "Authentication details were not provided."

It appears as if the space is causing issues due to being a json object? Is there any clean way to work around this? I must use the application/json type as I use the same program with a lot more code for other api requests which require the application/json type.

Comment: In your python code you have `url=d6bf96a81a58bf6e99ad1f819b244242797c0c07`. Is that correct?

Comment: That's a copy/paste error. I manually typed this out. Will correct, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: You can also try to remove the `application/json` from the headers and do `requests.post(url, headers=headers, data={'status': 'Good', 'value': 'Foobar'})`

Comment: I've tried that also and it didn't work, but I'd also like to keep the application/json for some of my other api requests that I leverage requests for.